# SQL Counting Distinct Rows and outputting answers

Tags: sql, count, row, distinct

I am trying to count distinct rows in table in sql that will output a value that corresponds to the orders..

I have CustomerID and OrderNumber and if a customer places more than 1 order in the system on a particular day I want to be able to label each distinct order with a number like below (The number will need to increase with every change or ordernumber from multiple rows (As the rows also contain each item purchased)

```
OrderNumber CustomerID      Seq Number
BINV0024536 FOBJAMBLU       1
BINV0024536 FOBJAMBLU       1
BINV0024789 FOBJAMBLU       2
BINV0024789 FOBJAMBLU       2
```

Comment: Please provide DBMS info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL SERVER you may use DENSE_RANK().

```
SELECT OrderNumber, CustomerID, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CustomerID, OrderNumber) AS  Seq 
FROM [YOURTABLE]
```

If you want to reset you seq with different customerID then you also have to use PARTITION

```
SELECT OrderNumber, CustomerID, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerID, OrderNumber) AS  Seq 
FROM [YOURTABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate virtual rownum and join it from another select:

```
SELECT ot.orderNumber, ot.customerId, usr.rowCounter
    FROM Order ot
        INNER JOIN
           (SELECT otr.orderNumber, otr.customerId, rownum as rowCounter
               FROM Order otr
               GROUP BY otr.orderNumber, otr.customerId
               ORDER BY otr.orderNumber, otr.customerId
           ) usr
           ON usr.orderNumber = ot.orderNumber AND usr.customerId = ot.orderNumber
```